# Computing the nilradical of a ring

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, nilpotence, artinian, semi-simple-rings

Let $R=\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{C} & \mathbb{C} & \mathbb{C}\\
0 & \mathbb{C} & \mathbb{C}\\
0 & \mathbb{C} & \mathbb{C}
\end{pmatrix}$. I want to find the nilradical: $$N(R)=\sum\{I: I \text{ is a nilpotent ideal of } R\}.$$

The observation is that $N:=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \mathbb{C} & \mathbb{C}\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ is a nilpotent set. Then define map $$\phi: R \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{C} & 0 & 0\\
0 & \mathbb{C} & \mathbb{C}\\
0 & \mathbb{C} & \mathbb{C}
\end{pmatrix} \cong\mathbb{C} \oplus M_2(\mathbb{C}), 
\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\
0 & d & e\\ 
0 & f & g\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \left(a, \begin{pmatrix} d & e\\
f & g\end{pmatrix} \right).$$ Indeed, $\phi$ is a surjective ring homomorphism and clearly ker$(\phi)=N$ and so by the First Isomorphism Theorem for Rings, $R/N\cong\text{Im}(\phi) =\mathbb{C} \oplus M_2(\mathbb{C}).$

I do not understand the next steps in the argument which are that this must be semisimple and so $N(R) \subseteq N$. Furthermore, $N$ is nilpotent so $N \subseteq N(R)$, hence $N=N(R)$.

I would appreciate any hints here. I am not sure if this follows from the Artin-Wedderburn Theorem or otherwise.

Comment: What is your definition of the nilradical of a non-commutative ring?

Comment: I have added the definition into the question.

Comment: Could you explain please why $\mathbb{C} \oplus M_2(\mathbb{C})$ is semisimple, and explain why then $R/N$ being semisimple then gives $N(R) \subseteq R$.